# Using TimeStamp, to define name of .txt log file

Tags: c++, string, directory, output, logfile

Im working on a system, where i want to incooporate a log in form of a .txt file.
This file should be created everytime the program is started, and will in the future be written to, when i've created all my errorcodes.

To keep these log files unique, i wanted to use timestamp. For getting these stamps i've used the following code:

```
 string GetDateStamp() {
    time_t     now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char       stamp[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(stamp, sizeof(stamp), "%Y-%m-%d-%X", &tstruct);

    return stamp;
}
```

This function is then called in another function, where i check if the dir for the log is created, if it is not, then it creates it.

```
void OpenNewLogFile(string& filepath)
{
    string datestamp;
    string logpath = filepath + "Log\\";
    if (_mkdir(logpath.c_str()) == 0)
    {
        cout << "dir created" << endl;
    }
    else if(_mkdir(logpath.c_str()) == EEXIST)
    {
        cout << "dir already exists" << endl;
    }
    else if (_mkdir(logpath.c_str()) == ENOENT)
    { 
    
        cout << "path could not be found" << endl;
    
    }

    ofstream outfile;
    datestamp = GetDateStamp();
    string createFile=""; 
    createFile = logpath + datestamp + ".txt";
    cout << createFile << endl;
    outfile.open(createFile);
}
```

The code is present in a header file, and called upon from my main cpp.
The output i get now, is the path as follows:

C:...\Log\2020-08-10-15:59:22.txt

but no .txt file appears in my log dir.

Maybe the solution is right in front of me, but sadly i cannot see it.

Hope some of you can help me out :-)

Comment: If you are using windows, then the colon ````:```` is not allowed in file names

Comment: damn. A solution for that could be to remove the time stamp, and just leave the date i suppose.

Comment: Another solution would be to replace the colons with a different symbol

Comment: Of course :-) Thanks guys!